# Runnable Jar file - src file path issue

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I've to read all the java file names available in scripts package to execuete a particular method.
The below code works fine using eclipse.
I want to run the Test using Runnable Jar - as the **strTestScriptsPath = "src/com/xyz/test/scripts"**  contains src, It is getting failed
(Otherwise I've to provide src folder to the JAR file to run it successfully)

In this context how to use   **this.getClass().getResourceAsStream()**

Note: I am trying to give path of the directory not the file. I've to fectch file name from the above code only :(

[image]

```
        public static boolean executeKeyword(String keyword){
            String strTestScriptsPath = "src/com/xyz/test/scripts";     

            File folder = new File( strTestScriptsPath );

            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

            boolean booFindMethod = false;
            findKeyword:
            for(File file: listOfFiles ){


                strJavaClassFileName = FilenameUtils.removeExtension( file.getName());                          
                strJavaClassFileName =  "com.xyz.test.scripts." + strJavaClassFileName;             

                System.out.println(strJavaClassFileName);

                // Reflection API code to call the required method from the class
                ..
                ..

            }
        }
```

Comment: jar file should lie in ../src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution from the web. 
Here is method that can get the list of classes from a package from JAR file.

```
 public static List<String> getJarFileListing(String jarLocation, String filter) {
        List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (jarLocation == null) {
            return files; // Empty.
        }

        // Lets stream the jar file 
        JarInputStream jarInputStream = null;
        try {
            jarInputStream = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(jarLocation));
            JarEntry jarEntry;

            // Iterate the jar entries within that jar. Then make sure it follows the
            // filter given from the user.
            do {
                jarEntry = jarInputStream.getNextJarEntry();
                if (jarEntry != null) {
                    String fileName = jarEntry.getName();

                    // The filter could be null or has a matching regular expression.
                    if (filter == null || fileName.matches(filter)) {
                        files.add(fileName);
                    }
                }
            }
            while (jarEntry != null);
            jarInputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to get Jar input stream from '" + jarLocation + "'", ioe);
        }
        return files;
    }
```

And call the above function..

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    List<String> listOfFiles = getJarFileListing("C:\Users\abc\xyz.jar","^com/xyz/test/scripts(.*)");
    /* Reflection API code */
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hanuman, if you want to create a runnable jar, you need to configure manifest file by provide fully qualified class name. Along with that this class should have:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Detailed information is available on: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/85application/jar/jar.html

Comment: @ Nikhil , Thanks for the response. I've provided the Main class which has main method And the JAR is running. The problem here is whth the path inside the code.Please read the question once again

Comment: 1. Do you have read access on the folder. 2. com.xyz.test.scripts.<strJavaClassFileName> is accurate, it will be helpful if you can post image of your project structure. 3. You have included test package as part of your JAR? Please check it using command: jar tf jar-file-name

Comment: As I said this is the issue with the line strTestScriptsPath = "src/com/xyz/test/scripts";   

Since JAR file contains com/xyz/test/scripts as file structure, it is not able to find src.

Comment: Can you exclude src folder from JAR file and use -- String strTestScriptsPath = "com/xyz/test/scripts"; -- See if that works. Also if possible, please post image of your project structure.